# Best practice navigationDrawer and tabs in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I trying to create tabs in Android. My main activity contains a view with a navigation drawer (Listview) and a framelayout for the content so i need to use Fragments for each menu item. I think this is the usual way to build an app wit a "left side slide out" menu?

In my main_fragment (2nd menu item, app.Fragment) i need a tab control with 2 tabs. In each tab i need to load a fragment (app.Fragment, becouse 1 fragment contains a map v2 which works with app.Fragment only (in my case)). So i have a rab_mapview and a tab_listview fragment

The tab_Mapview and tab_Listview tab fragments are both app.Fragment fragments.
I struggling for 2 days to get this done... but i cant fix it :'-( I constanly having problems with support.v4.........Fragment and app.Fragment compatability problems OR that i cant get the solution i found working in a fragment (only in an activity, what i cant load in the FrameLayout)

I found and tryed something with:

- TabHost
- TabLayout
- Actionbar tabs???

Which is the right one in my situation and how do i implement it on the right way?

---

A little scatch from my wish (above are tabs, under in the layout are 3 buttons) [image]

My main_activity layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fr_content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_menu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My main_fragment layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="aaeu.app.presentationlayer.MainFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/all_alerts"
            android:id="@+id/btn_all_alerts"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/amber_alerts"
            android:id="@+id/btn_ambert_alerts"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/endangered_missings"
            android:id="@+id/btn_missings"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

My onCreateView from my main_fragment. This code doesn't work anyway

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getContext()));

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return v;
}
```

---

Iam new with android so it would great when someone can post a simple (working) example with:

- a main activity with a working slide out menu from the left.
- when i click on 1 menu item, the main_fragement wil open
- the main fragment contains a tab controll with 2 tabs
- each tab opens a app.fragment fragment

When it is posible i wanna use the best practice for this situation. When someone will be so nice to make this simple example would be great so i can see how the best practice for this situation works in detail i can use it for other projects too.

Comment: looking for the same, did you get anything, if yes please share

Comment: You are looking for a menu and one of the opened menu items need to show a tabview ?, I got this working. I use EVERYWHERE `android.support.v4.app.XXX` components (Fragment, maps aso)